# discord.js Link blocker

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently trying to code a Discord link blocker:

My code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
    }
    if (message.content.includes('discordapp.com/')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
    if (message.content.includes('https:')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
    if (message.content.includes('http:')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
    if (message.content.includes('www.')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
  })
```

How can I put all keywords (http: ; discord.gg/ ; etc.) in a single "if part"?

I would need that, because I want the bot to write the message only once, even if you write "https://discord.gg/" for example. If you just write "https://discord.gg/" the message comes twice because of first "https://" and once because of "discord.gg/".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - else if**

When one of the `if` statements matches, all following `else if` blocks are skipped.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
    }
    else if (message.content.includes('discordapp.com/')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
    else if (message.content.includes('https:')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
    else if (message.content.includes('http:')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
    else if (message.content.includes('www.')) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
        }
  })
```

**Option 2 - regex**

You can combine all the searches into one [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.match(/discord\.gg|discordapp\.com|https?:|www\./) !== null) {
        message.delete()
        .then(message.channel.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_chat_message))
        .then(message.member.send('<@!' + message.member + '>' + config.link_deleted_dm_message))
    }
  })
```

Comment: I think `RegExp#test()` would be more appropriate than `String#match()` in this situation. Furthermore, although I think regex is the best approach, you could make an array of every banned string, and use `Array#some()` to iterate through all of them for a match, resulting in only one if block. `bannedLinks.some((str) => message.content.includes(str))`